# How to apply constraint on a couple of matrix values in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, quadratic-programming

I have a matrix A of size m x m

[image]

and while using scipy, I need to define the inequality constraint in python for items of this matrix that verifies:

[image].

I managed to define the bounds between -1 and 1 :

[image]

in python as follows:

```py
# -1 <= a[i][j] <= 1
bnds_a_s_t = [(-1,1) for _ in range(np.size(A))]
```

But I don't know how to define the inequality constraint. Should I use a for loop with 2 pointers and add them to a list of inequality constraints? In this case, what should I return from the inequality function? In the equations, M is a list of size m.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Since scipy consists of many submodules, you have to be more specific, i.e. what method are you are trying to use?

Comment: @joni I provided a minimal reproducible example in the answer below, thank you in advance for checking it when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in a nonlinear programming you can use have a matrix that is constrained by construction, starting with an arbitrary matrix A, you can use, for instance

```py
def constrained(A):
  return np.tanh(A - A.T);
```

The matrix `a = A - A.T` will ensure that `a[t,s] + a[s,t] = 0` the tanh is such that `tanh(-x) = -tanh(x)`, so the identity will be preserved for `a = tanh(A - A.T)`, furthermore `-1 <= tanh(x) <= 1`. So `constrained(A)` gives what you need.

Comment: You see why you have to provide a minimum working example. I tried to guess what you wanted and I guessed wrong. What you must have is in your objective function implementation compute `a = np.reshape(a, (n,n)); a = np.tanh(A - np.transpose(A))` and then use a (that satisfy your constraints) to compute the objective value.